# SQL query collation trouble

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I have a select query something like

```
SELECT
  itemCode,
  itemDefinition,
  clientCode,
  clientDefinition
FROM
  Invoices
```

Invoice table in the database has the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

The problem is when I receive data  in my program, Turkish characters in column `itemDefinition` and `clientDefinition` doesn't seem properly. For example Turkish letter Ğ becomes some other character, Ş something else etc.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What are the `DataTypes` you used for a `Table`, can u provide your Table Schema..?

Comment: varchar(100) ... for column itemDefinition and clientDefinition

Comment: use nvarchar(100), it will work..

Comment: I cant because , database is belong to a one ERP program and I have no right to change it ...some other solution ?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS is code page 1252 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252   Ğ is not in that code page

Comment: I know it is not supporting those turkish characters... for example when I ve got result in my program. it shows Ý instead of İ... how can I correct this in query level... that is the problem..

Comment: What makes you think you can fix this at the query level? Ğ is not in codepage 1252 so it is not in the database.  A query cannot generate a char not in the table.  That table has a place holder (probably ?) for any character it could not map.

Comment: when I write a character İ directly to the table by management studio it turns it to char "I", in addtion to that  when look the record in ERP application which uses this database I can see that char İ properly but when I query it by my application I got result Ý, so there should be some way to get it as İ or I

Comment: So it is correct in SSMS and the ERP application but not your application.  And you still think it is a problem with the query.

Comment: and if those charecters are not in the table how ERP program shows them properly ?

Comment: as it is in image in ERP PROGRAM itemDefinition is like ...MİNİ but in query result it is MÝNÝ ... so I need to get it as MİNİ... how ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution is like this : firstly, need to create function for character convertion as in below :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ChangetoTRK](@A NVARCHAR(4000))    
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)      
AS    
BEGIN   
  DECLARE @TMP NVARCHAR(4000)     
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@A COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(208), N'Ğ')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(220), N'Ü')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(222), N'Ş')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(221), N'İ')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(214), N'Ö')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(199), N'Ç')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(73), N'I')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(240), N'ğ')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(252), N'ü')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(254), N'ş')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(105), N'i')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(246), N'ö')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(231), N'ç')
  SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, CHAR(253), N'ı')
  RETURN @TMP
END
```

then , we use it in query as :

```
SELECT
  itemCode,
  dbo.ChangeToTRK(itemDefinition),
  clientCode,
  dbo.ChangeToTRK(clientDefinition)
```

FROM
      Invoices